Как удалить комиты в Bitbucket
Я случайно запушил коммита которые хотел удалить и теперь они находят в моем удаленном репозитории. Я пытался сначала удалить их в своем локальном репозитории. И запушить новую ветку без этих коммита но мне вылезает ошибка что моя локалная версия отличается от удаленной и что мне сначала нужно сделать pull, но тогда ко мне подтянуться изменения которые я хочу удалить как я могу удалить комиты из Bitbucket
